# m2eclipse downloads source, but in eclipse I do not see a source attachment

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse, m2e

I am confused about m2eclipse.

Sometimes while debugging, I see for example

The JAR file ~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.3.4.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar has no source attachment.

Then the plugin downloads spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE-sources.jar to my local repo, and the source appears in my eclipse editor.

But when I look in Build path, Libraries at the spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE entry, I see Source attachment: None.

Also at the Debug configuration, Source, I see nothing.

Answer (score 0):

click here [download here Java source attacher](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-source-attacher)

and download the Java source attacher jar file and then paste to the plugin folder and restart the eclipse.
Then attach the java source shown in below. Done！！！！
[image: see image how to download]

[image]